# c# OrderByDescending issue if DateTime is same

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I trying to sort list by `DateTime` in `descending` order. I have tried this.

```
list.Records = list.Records.OrderByDescending(w => w.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

It give me correct record in `descending` order when `CreatedOn` is difference. But the issue occurs when there is same record CreatedOn time.

[image]

In above image I have two record in list. Here `DateTime` of two record is same. What I want here 2nd record should come first. Action `Select Record` should come first and `Auto Assign` should come on 2nd. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ThenByDescending`:

```
list.Records = list.Records.OrderByDescending(w => w.CreatedOn)
                           .ThenByDescending(x => x.Action)
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. In other case I have few more action there in that case how it will work?

Comment: this will sort records that has the same DateTime value based on `Action` in descending order

Comment: @AjayPunekar What type is `Action`? If it's a string, this should work.

Comment: @AjayPunekar What is the type of `CreatedOn`? May be there is milliseconds difference between two rows?

Comment: I tried by same Millisecond instead of action but not worked. CreateOn is MySQL Date time

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think it's worked. Sorry it was my mistake. I used other column instead of `Action` column